# How to create calculated field column for sorting the numbers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

I have three columns

```
value1 value2 value3
 (100   100     80)
 (100   100     100)
 (70    40     50)
```

I want to sort this by concatenating all these and padding left 0 and then sort it.
Can any one help me out, how can I write the formula.

Comment: Rishabh, can you add the Output you want from this Input of 3 rows in you question so we understand what is it you want to sort first or concatenate.

Comment: Also, please mark the answer as accepted if any of the below answered solved your problem

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping me out, I got it. your solutions helped me a lot .. thanks again Denny and Tanmay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use the MAX function to get the highest from 3 values
- Append leading 000 to the result (padding left you mean, I presume)
- Then use the RIGHT function to get the last 3 digits

Available Functions and Syntax List is at https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Off the top of my head (so likely wrong, as it is 08:00 here in Amsterdam and I haven't finished my first coffee yet)

```
= RIGHT( "000" & MAX( value1,value2,value3 ) , 3 )
```

Comment: Thanks Danny for the help. I am getting the max value from the row.I am looking for something like row 1 =100 70 80 where 100 is from value 1 column 70 is from value 2 and 80 from value 3 and same with other two rows  100 100 80 and 100 100 100..I am sorry if I am not clear..I will look at the link which you have shared..Thanks again :) and I hope you would have had your coffee..

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

**Step 1** : Sort the numbers (Formula below). To keep the formula concise I had to user "123","321"etc. They represent the order of values. So, "123" means order in ascending i.e. value1 value2 and then value3

```
    IF( Value1<Value2
        , IF( Value1<Value3
              , IF( Value2<Value3
                    ,"123"
                    ,"132"
                  )
              ,"312"
            )
        , IF( Value2<Value3
              , IF( Value1<Value3
                    ,"213"
                    ,"231"
                  )
              ,"321"
            )
       )
```

**Step 2** : Since you now have the base ready, you can replace "123" etc with whatever you want (padding with zeros) in your case

Here are some tests that i ran. Check out the screen shot below.

[image]
Hope it helps